# Change Android Drawable Button Icon Programmatically

Tags: java, android, drawable

How would one change the `android:src` XML property programatically of a FloatingActionButton or Button widget? I have a button defined as following within an activity:

```
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) this.findViewById(R.id.start_button);
```

It has an initial `android:src` set as follows:

```
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
```

I'm trying to utilize the [setImageResource(int id)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)) to change the `android:src` XML property, but how to I access a Drawable icon such as `ic_media_pause` after a button click that occurs for example. When I try to pass in `R.drawable.ic_media_pause` to the `setImageResource()` method I received an cannot resolve symbol error.

`floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_pause);`

How do I get at the available [R.drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html#ic_media_play) resources to pass it in as an argument.

Any help would be great appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a file called "ic_media_pause" in your res/drawable folder or is this a default android icon included in the SDK? If so, try `android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause`

Comment: I'm using the default android icon library included in the SDK. Your suggestion absolutely worked. You should post a response. On a side note, could I use `get.Resources.getIdentifier()` to get a the default android icon library?

Comment: Yes, you could, but according to the docs, it's discouraged.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html

Comment: So if I had a custom image resource in the drawable folder, for example, I'd want to use `R.drawable.custom_image` rather than use the `getResources().getIdentifier("custom_image", "drawable", getPackage())`? That's what they mean by discouraged and to use identifier instead?

Comment: It's discouraged because using the predefined identifiers is faster than using `getIdentifier()`. There are most likely common use-cases which require `getIdentifier()`.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You're trying to access a default icon included in the SDK. You need to prefix your resource identifier with "android." For example:

```
floatingActionButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
```

this will allow you to reference the default icons.

:)